# How can I remove unwanted preinstalled apps from macOS?

Tags: macos, applications, permission, sudo

In macOS there are a lot of pre-installed bloatware applications. I know that I will never use them. Examples of such apps are: Chess, Stocks, Messages, TV and so on.

While some of them may not take up much disk space, they are cluttering the application list and Launchpad menu, so I wanted to get rid of them.

When I tried to delete such applications, I got an error saying that I have no permission to do it. So is it possible to remove apple bloatware from macOS?

There was the same question in [2011](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23843/how-can-i-remove-unwanted-apps-such-as-chess-or-address-book-from-my-mac) and in [2012](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65169/is-it-possible-to-delete-the-useless-apps-pre-installed-on-my-mac). They contains info that is no more actual. This question is an update for 2021. I am asking about macOS v10.15.7 (Catalina) or later.

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 3):

On macOS 10.15.7 Catalina I needed to remount root volume as read-write first:

```
sudo mount -u -o rw /
```

Then I made a deletion with:

```
cd /System/Applications/
sudo rm -rf Chess.app TV.app ...
```

Comment: And presumably you also turned off SIP first, or that wouldn't have worked.

Comment: I ma sorry, what is SIP (System Integrity Protection)? Is is specific to Apple hardware? Note, I am doing this on a macOS virtual machine from Linux.

Comment: SIP is the whole point, @Ashark... Apple does not let you change `/System` just like that. You have to disable SIP in recovery (which I assume only exists on physical Macs).